# Extension of Polynomial Rings is Integral

Tags: algebraic-geometry, solution-verification, algebraic-number-theory

Given an (infinite) field $K$ and let $R := K[x_1, \dots ,x_n]$. Let further $(f)$ be a principal ideal of $R$ generated by a polynomial $f$ which is  monic in the variable $x_n$. I want to show that $R/(f)$ is an integral extension of the ring $R' = K[x_1, \dots ,x_{n-1}]$.

My idea for this was the following: Let $g \in R$ be an arbitrary polynomial and write it as $$g = g_0 + g_1x_n + \dots + g_mx_n^m$$ where each $g_i$ is an element of $R'$. Similarly write $f$ as $$f = f_0 + f_1x_n + \dots + f_{k-1}x_n^{k-1} + x_n^k$$ so $k$ will be the degree of $f$ in the variable $x_n$. Reducing $g$ mod $(f)$ we see, that $g$ will be congruent to some polynomial in $R$, where the degree in the variable $x_n$ will be less than $k$.

(Writing this out is tedious but the idea is the following. We start by looking at the summand of highest degree $$g_mx_n^m = g_m x_n^{m-k} f - (g_m x_n^{m-k} f - g_mx_n^m) \equiv (g_m x_n^{m-k} f - g_mx_n^m)$$ And writing the last term explicitly, we will see, that the degree is reduced by one. Repeating this sufficiently often we are done.)

Now to conclude I want to argue that this shows us that the ring $R/(f)$ can be embedded into the direct sum $$L := R' \oplus R'x_n \oplus  \dots \oplus R'x_n^{k-1}$$ Then, since $L$ is integral over $R'$ we are done.

The main problem I have with this reasoning is that the procedure above does not proof that this is indeed an embedding of $R$ into $L$, i.e. the "embedding" may not actually be injective.

Maybe I am overlooking something obvious here. If not, I am interested if this idea can be made into a proof, or if not some explanation as to why. I'd prefer hints over an actual solution. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sums and products of integral elements are again integral. (This takes a bit of work, but it's a standard result.) Hence an algebra generated by integral elements is an integral extension. Thus, because $R$ is generated by $x_n$, it suffices to show that $x_n$ is integral over $K[x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}]$. But this is clear because $f$ is monic.

Comment: Thankyou. So $x_n$ as and Element of $R/(f)$ is integral over $K[x_1, \dots , x_{n-1}]$ since $f_0 + f_1x_n + \dots + f_{k-1}x_n^{k-1} + x_n^k = f \equiv 0$ in $R/(f)$ so it satisfies a monic polynomial equation.

This is really much easier. Still, does my argument fail, or could it be improved to an actual prove?